# How do I turn a dictionary with lists as values into a list of dictionaries with single values?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have this dict:

```
{
  'x': [0,1,2],
  'y': ['a','b','c']
}
```

A dictionary where all the values are lists, of identical length.

I want to produce this:

```
[
  { 'x': 0, 'y': 'a' },
  { 'x': 1, 'y': 'b' },
  { 'x': 2, 'y': 'c' }
]
```

Is there an efficient way to do this? Hopefully using something in `itertools`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
[dict(zip(d, vals)) for vals in zip(*d.values())]
```

For example:

```
>>> d = {'y': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'x': [0, 1, 2]}
>>> [dict(zip(d, vals)) for vals in zip(*d.values())]
[{'y': 'a', 'x': 0}, {'y': 'b', 'x': 1}, {'y': 'c', 'x': 2}]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[dict(stuff) for stuff in zip(*[[(k, v) for v in vs] for k, vs in myDict.iteritems()])]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[{'x': v, 'y': d['y'][i]} for i, v in enumerate(d['x'])]
```

Comment: This works only in the very specific case of 'x' and 'y' being the keys, when that was probably only an example (there might be more than two keys, and the keys might not be known in advance).

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {
  'x': [0,1,2],
  'y': ['a','b','c']
}
values = zip(*d.values())
print [dict(zip(d.keys(), v)) for v in values]
```